# Armature not working when trying to rotate using the mouse?

Tags: transforms, armature

When I am trying to rotate the bone on the armature, I am getting the arrows to rotate the bone but the bone is not actually rotating.

I have tried parenting the armature to a character and it is still doing the same thing, the bone will not rotate with the mouse but it will rotate when using the XYZ rotation values.

**[Blendfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sjcmhc4bzb939ke/Armitures%20%20BLEND%201.blend)**

Answer (score 6):

That's because you enabled **Manipulate center points** in the header. Click that icon to toggle it off, or press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> (comma).

[image]

Comment: now is 2020 and i just got hit by the same mysterious "blender all-of-sudden stopped to work with bones" problem. Thanks!